# Example of 2D k-space models allowing interband transitions after a closed-loop trajectory?

Tags: condensed-matter, model-hamiltonians, quantum-mechanics, berry-phase

I have been mainly exposed to 2D momentum-space condensed matter models in the context of Berry-related topology. I now want to study models where, if I take a closed loop in momentum space, I will have the possibility of an interband transition governed by selection rules.
So far, all I have seen are charge-pumping-like effects with the Rice-Mele model (quantized flux pumping after one closed loop trajectory; [example](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2021)). I have seen some 2D models for excitons as well ([example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.08310)), but these don't consider a loop explicitly. Additionally, I understand that there is a perspective of *[potential virtual transitions](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2515-7639/abf0b5/pdf)* associated with Berry curvature (due to its inherent interband character). However, I am looking for something more concrete than that.

I have read a bit about [Landau-Zener transitions](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Emlittman/landau_zener.pdf), but most works I have seen involve the time variable explicitly ([example of selection rules](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0977.pdf)). **However, I am looking for an example of a model that studies interband transitions and selections rules in the context of a closed loop in k-space** (very likely parameterized by parameter $t$: $(k_x(t),k_y(t))$. Since I have a ways to go in familiarizing myself with the field, I was hoping someone could suggest a resource that features such a model.

Comment: I guess these would be non-adiabatic cases, and I have only been looking at adiabatic ones.

Comment: Or, if it is adiabatic, I think the trajectory should go through a gapless point... So, maybe this question might be hard to answer?

Comment: Hi TribalChief! Long time no chat! How did things go with this question? Did you find an answer?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.